# How to make a call rake console, these settings are set by default?

Tags: ruby, linux, rake

How to make a call rake console, these settings are set by default?

```
2.3.0: 001> (ENV [ 'BATTLE_NET_REGION'] = 'eu') and (ENV [ 'BATTLE_NET_LOCALE'] = 'ru_RU') and (ENV [ 'BATTLE_NET_KEY'] = 'my_battle_net_key')
```

rake task:

```
require "bundler/gem_tasks"
require "rspec/core/rake_task"

RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)

task default: :spec

desc 'Open an irb session preloaded with this library'
task :console do
  sh 'irb -rubygems -I lib -r wowrb.rb'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add tho variables to the shell command:

```
task :console do
  sh 'BATTLE_NET_REGION=eu BATTLE_NET_LOCALE=ru_RU BATTLE_NET_KEY=my_battle_net_key irb -rubygems -I lib -r wowrb.rb'
end
```

But why do you use a rake task to start a irb console? Would it be easier to start it directly or with a small shell script or alias that sets all variables?

Comment: When I use irb get the error:

2.3.0 :002 > Wowrb.item(18803)
NameError: uninitialized constant Wowrb from (irb):2 from /home/art/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in <main>

Comment: What is `Wowrb`? An external library? Did you miss to require that library? Please post your script.

Comment: Do you try to run that file directly? What will not work, that's a gem that needs to be require and you need to write your own code on top.